# Ext. USB HDD crashed - managed to recover files, but family videos seem corrupted. Anybody know how to fix them?

Tags: video, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

Last night I had everybody's worst nightmare. My external 2TB drive crashed, with all my family videos and photos on it. Right now you're all facepalming, but yes, I didn't have another backup. Not a mistake I will repeat again!

I started with Recuva, which was useless and allowed me to recover 1 file. I then switched to iCare Data Recovery and that did a much better job. It allowed me to see all the files! So I "recovered" the photos and videos folder. I was overjoyed until I actually tried to play the videos...none of them work. The photos however, seemed to display their thumbnails and work after a while, although they didn't immediately.

I have tried WMP, Windows Media Player Classic, Winamp...nothing opens the vids. The error shows as "Cannot render file". I simply must recover these videos as they are the only ones we have of our children. The videos are in various formats (.mov, .3gp, .mts).

Does anyone know how I can fix them? I am using Win 8.1.

Thanks!

Comment: when you recovered the data, you did so to another drive, right? Unfourtunately since your videos use many differant codecs, we can't really recommend fixer utilities. you will have to search for them extension by extension. better bet is to go back to your original disk and try recovering them again using better tools and methodologies. Also, since you have recovered a good bit of your data already, don't throw out the stuff you already saved, thinking you can just re-recover it. recovery can often be an itterative process, so take the good from each step.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I am trying a different recovery method now, and then once I have recovered some of my data I will try a chkdsk /f.

Comment: Woop woop! Spent 8hrs scanning with EaseUS data recovery and it worked like a charm. Easily the best of the data recovery tools I tried!

Answer (score 0):

I am a tightwad so I would try to use that drive again.  If so, I would run SpinRite which is available at GRC.com for $89 dollars. Once SpinRite has identified the bad sectors and relocated the data, the drive's SMART system should be able to keep the drive operational for quite a while.  If money is a consideration, it could serve as a local backup or storage if you use other backup methods. If you don't want to take the risk, donate it or give it away (with full disclosure of course!)  It could chug along for years - or not.

Written by Security Now's Steve Gibson, SpinRite can be used on any operating system and any file system. This means it can run on drives formatted with Windows XP's/Vista's/Windows 7's NTFS and all other older FAT formats (in addition to all Linux, Novell, and all other file systems.)

Follow the instructions download the ISO and create a live CD (or other bootable media), including its own bootable FreeDOS operating system.  There is a step-by-step video at https://www.grc.com/sr/whatitdoes.htm

I use SpinRite for drive maintenance as well as to pre-qualify hard drives before first use. Drives on non-PC platforms, such as Apple Macintosh or TiVo, may be temporarily relocated to a PC motherboard for data recovery, maintenance and repair by SpinRite. SpinRite provides complete interaction with IDE-interface PATA (parallel ATA) and SATA (Serial ATA) drives, and it can also be used with any other type of drive — SCSI, USB, 1394/Firewire — that can be made visible to DOS through the addition of controller BIOS or add-on DOS drivers.

SpinRite is a must have" tools for the computer pro or serious hobbyist.  Since EaseUS worked well for you, I'll look into that tool as well.

After you are done, do your backup. :-)